# How to display listview in phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am facing problem for display values as list view in phone gap android..My server connection is working..pls help

```
 function display()
{

  $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        $("#list").append("<li>"+title+"</li>");
          alert('Data successfully display');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('There was an error');
    }
  });
```

body

```
 <div data-role="content">

    <div class="example-wrapper">
    <input onclick="display()" type="button" value="display" />
     <ul data-role="listview"  id="list" data-theme="a"> </ul>


    </div>
```

php

```
 <?php
    include_once('config/config.php');
    $sql = 'SELECT title FROM mydiary';
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode($row['title']);
    }

    ?>
```

When i try to click display button am getting error alert.

Comment: what is the actual url here? url: 'url'

Comment: What is the error alert you are getting?

Comment: @radhu try a JsonP request as cross domain ajax calls are not allowed due to Same Origin Policy.

Comment: url: 'http://000.000.0.000/data/display.php',..i am using correct url..i checked in browser..am geting result..sory cant put real url..

Comment: error: function(){
        alert('There was an error');...am getting this alert...

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain ajax calls are restricted due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you are targeted on modern devices or browsers, you can make cross domain requests using [Cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Else better stick with use  [JsonP Plugin](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp).

[More info on JsonP](http://json-p.org/)

Hope it helps